# How can I save NoScript settings in Tor?

Tags: configuration

After restarting the Tor browser the edited settings of NoScript gets resetted every time. I want to forbid JavaScript. It's annoying i have to edit the settings every time after starting Tor. How can I save them??? That must be possible somehow.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As you only mentioned javascript, you can disable it without using NoScript.
Simply click the onion on the upper left part of your screen, navigate to security settings and put security level to "Best". Now javascript is always disabled.

[image: Tor slider settings]